# Discrete Mathematics - Perfect square proof with non-constructive approach.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The questions reads the following:

Prove that either

$2 * 10^{500} + 15$  or

$2 * 10^{500} + 16$

is not a perfect square using the non-constructive approach.

Comment: The only perfect squares that differ by $1$ are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Answer (score 7):

This comes down to the question of whether there are any two other perfect
squares that differ by 1 besides 1 and 0. Assume for the sake of contradiction
that there is. Say $p$ and $p+1$ are perfect squares. Then
$\exists k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} . k^2 = p$ and
$\exists l \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} . l^2 = p+1 = k^2 + 1.$
What this says is that $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \wedge
\sqrt{k^2 + 1} \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. We know $k = 0$ satisfies this,
but what about $k = 1$? $k = 2$? In fact, will $\sqrt{k^2+1}$ every be rational
for $k > 0$? I'll leave this as an exercise for you to prove.